# WebView Content

Tags: android, html, webview, format

So basically I've got a webview displaying a HTML/PHP page, what I want to do is for this webview not to display or not load a certain section of the page or an HTML 'div' that is named 'xgDock' as this 'div' doesn't display correctly in webview and is unnecessary for my app.

Thanks very much for your time and thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is my webview fragment.java

```
public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment implements BackPressFragment {

//Static
public static final String HIDE_NAVIGATION = "hide_navigation";
public static final String LOAD_DATA = "loadwithdata";

//References
private Activity mAct;
private FavDbAdapter mDbHelper;

//Layout with interaction
private WebView browser;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

//Layouts
private ImageButton webBackButton;
private ImageButton webForwButton;
private LinearLayout ll;

//HTML5 video
private View mCustomView;
private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Return the existing layout if there is a savedInstance of this fragment
    if (savedInstanceState != null) { return ll; }

    ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview,
            container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    browser = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.refreshlayout);

    // settings some settings like zooming etc in seperate method for
    // suppresslint
    browserSettings();

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // Make sure any url clicked is opened in webview
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if ((url.contains("market://") || url.contains("mailto:")
                    || url.contains("play.google") || url.contains("tel:") || url
                    .contains("vid:")) == true) {
                // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                return true;
            }
            // Return true to override url loading (In this case do
            // nothing).
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(browser, url);

            adjustControls();
        }

    });

    // has all to do with progress bar
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            } else if (progress < 100){
                //If we do not hide the navigation, show refreshing
                if (!WebviewFragment.this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
                        WebviewFragment.this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false)
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,
                                     WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                onHideCustomView();
                return;
            }

            // 1. Stash the current state
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();

            // 2. Stash the custom view callback
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;

            // 3. Add the custom view to the view hierarchy
            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            decor.addView(mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


            // 4. Change the state of the window
            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            // 1. Remove the custom view
            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            decor.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;

            // 2. Restore the state to it's original form
            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()
                    .setSystemUiVisibility(mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);

            //TODO Find a better solution to the keyboard not showing after custom view is hidden
            //The user will come from landscape, so we'll first 'rotate' to portrait (rotation fixes a bug of the keybaord not showing)
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            //The we'll restore to the detected orientation (by immediately rotating back, the user should not notice any difference and/or flickering).
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

            // 3. Call the custom view callback
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            mCustomViewCallback = null;


        }

    });

    browser.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // setting an on touch listener
    browser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            browser.reload();
        }
    });

    return ll;
}// of oncreateview

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mAct = getActivity();

    setRetainInstance(true);

    String weburl = getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
    String data = getArguments().containsKey(LOAD_DATA) ? getArguments().getString(LOAD_DATA) : null;
    if (checkConnectivity() || weburl.startsWith("file:///android_asset/")) {
        //If this is the first time, load the initial url, otherwise restore the view if necessairy
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //If we have HTML data to load, do so, else load the url.
            if (data != null) {
                browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(weburl, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
            } else {
                browser.loadUrl(weburl);
            }
        } else if (mCustomView != null){
            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            ((ViewGroup) mCustomView.getParent()).removeView(mCustomView);
            decor.addView(mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    browser.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    browser.onResume();

    if (!this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
            this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false){

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) mAct)
            .getSupportActionBar();

        if (mAct instanceof WebviewActivity) {
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        } else {
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        }

        View view = mAct.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview_actionbar, null);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        actionBar.setCustomView(view, lp);

        webBackButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goBack);
        webForwButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goForward);

        webBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (browser.canGoBack())
                    browser.goBack();
            }
        });
        webForwButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (browser.canGoForward())
                    browser.goForward();
            }
        });
    } else {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }

    adjustControls();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (!this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
            this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false) {

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.share:
        shareURL();
        return true;
    case R.id.favorite:
        mDbHelper = new FavDbAdapter(mAct);
        mDbHelper.open();

        String title = browser.getTitle();
        String url = browser.getUrl();

        if (mDbHelper.checkEvent(title, url, FavDbAdapter.KEY_WEB)) {
            // This item is new
            mDbHelper.addFavorite(title, url, FavDbAdapter.KEY_WEB);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mAct,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_success),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mAct,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_duplicate),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
}

// Checking for an internet connection
private boolean checkConnectivity() {
    boolean enabled = true;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mAct
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if ((info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable())) {
        enabled = false;

        Helper.noConnection(mAct);
    }

    return enabled;
}

public void adjustControls() {
    webBackButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goBack);
    webForwButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goForward);

    if (webBackButton == null || webForwButton == null) return;

    if (browser.canGoBack()) {
        webBackButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
    } else {
        webBackButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    if (browser.canGoForward()) {
        webForwButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
    } else {
        webForwButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}

// sharing
private void shareURL() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String appname = getString(R.string.app_name);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            (getResources().getString(R.string.web_share_begin)) + appname
                    + getResources().getString(R.string.web_share_end)
                    + browser.getUrl());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources()
            .getString(R.string.share)));
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void browserSettings() {
    // set javascript and zoom and some other settings
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    // enable all plugins (flash)
    browser.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}

@Override
public boolean handleBackPress() {
    if (browser.canGoBack()){
        browser.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
 }
```

WebviewActivity.Java

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Toolbar mToolbar;

//Options to load a webpage
public static String URL = "webview_url";
public static String OPEN_EXTERNAL = "open_external";
public static String LOAD_DATA = WebviewFragment.LOAD_DATA;
public static String HIDE_NAVIGATION = WebviewFragment.HIDE_NAVIGATION;

String mWebUrl = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Determine if we want to open this as intent or in the webview
    boolean openInWebView = true;
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(OPEN_EXTERNAL) && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(OPEN_EXTERNAL) == true){
        //If we have to load data directly, we can only do this locally
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(LOAD_DATA)) {
            openInWebView = false;
        }
    }

    //Determine if we would like to fragment to display navigation, based on the passed bundle arguments
    boolean hideNavigation = false;
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(HIDE_NAVIGATION) && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == true){
        hideNavigation = true;
    }

    String data = null;
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(LOAD_DATA)){
        data = getIntent().getExtras().getString(LOAD_DATA);
    }

    //opening the webview fragment with passed url
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(URL)){
        mWebUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString(URL);
        if (openInWebView) {
            openWebFragmentForUrl(mWebUrl, hideNavigation, data);
        } else {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mWebUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

            //Shutdown this activity
            finish();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public void openWebFragmentForUrl(String url, boolean hideNavigation, String data){
    Fragment fragment;
    fragment = new WebviewFragment();

    // adding the data
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA, new String[]{url});
    bundle.putBoolean(WebviewFragment.HIDE_NAVIGATION, hideNavigation);
    if (data != null)
        bundle.putString(WebviewFragment.LOAD_DATA, data);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    //Changing the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

    //Setting the title
    if (data == null)
        setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.webview_title));
    else
        setTitle("");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment webview = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

    if (webview instanceof BackPressFragment) {
        boolean handled = ((WebviewFragment)webview).handleBackPress();
        if (!handled)
            super.onBackPressed();
    } else {         
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities:

- You can update the website:
  You add an extra paremeter to your request, ie: ?noxgdock
  You check this parameter on your php page.. if present, you don't add it.
  like this, you don't load this div for nothing.
- You can't update the website:
  You can remove the DIV after it is loaded with something like that:

  webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  "elem = document.getElementByName('xgDock'); if (elem) {elem.style.display = 'none; ';})()");

Or you [load the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350614/getting-the-html-source-code-with-a-url-in-an-android-application), remove the div, and only load it after. (but it can be painful if you have authentifications, cookies, ...)

Answer (score 0):

you can inject javascript into your HTML content via webview

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/

from there you can document.getElementByName("xgDock").style.xxxx and mess with CSS to hide it.